# Deleted words from a string

Tags: c#, string

Is there any possibility to delete specific words from a string? For exempla
string x ="documents\bin\debug" and I want to delete "\bin\debug".

Comment: the String.Replace() method might be what you're looking for

Comment: Specifically, use `string.Replace` to replace `"\bin\debug"` with `string.Empty`

Comment: tried that but after I used that nothing changed.This is what i want to do                                                                                                              `FileInfo f = new FileInfo(y);
           string z = f.FullName;
            z.Replace(@"\bin\debug",@"");`

Comment: @UngureanuGeorge Try my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`String.Replace()`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace):

```
string x = @"documents\bin\debug";
string desiredString = x.Replace(@"\bin\debug", String.Empty);
```

**Note:** The **key** thing here is that you have to assign the string returned by the `Replace()` function to a variable. (From your comment on the question, it *is* the problem). This can either be another variable (as in the above example) or the same variable:

```
string x = x.Replace(@"\bin\debug", String.Empty);
```

Implicitly, not assigning the return value to a variable (or using the former way) will keep the value of `x`, unchanged, which is the exact problem you're facing. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Wondering if the reason that it doesnt work is because I'm trying to get information of a file and after I'm trying to remove some of words...I'm doing this cause I have to open pdf file and I need my program to find the path to that file in order to move the app to other pc.So I cant set a specific path to that file.

Comment: @UngureanuGeorge But your question speaks otherwise... Debug the value of `x`. If it changes as you want, this answer is fine on its own. It doesn't need to meet the additional requirements of doing what you want to do, does it? That I may help you, can you explain what exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use string replace

```
string x = @"documents\bin\debug";
string nestring = x.Replace(@"\bin\debug", "");
Console.WriteLine(nestring);
```